# curl can not download file but browser can

Tags: curl, amazon-s3

URL example: https://xxxxxxxxxx.s3.amazonaws.com/xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx/xxxxxxxxxxxxx/x?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAIFKEBR4CLVTDYSLA&Signature=Kv%2B859dJ2eUmLgHdkT%2F9nUJEeRM%3D&Expires=1922517562

I tried to decode %XX but no success.

Also I tried `aws s3 cp s3://xxxxxxxxxx/xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx/xxxxxxxx... - --recursive` but `Streaming currently is only compatible with non-recursive cp commands` - I need to stream multiple files from S3.

Using `wget` I am getting the same 403.

URL from `s3_client.generate_presigned_url`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use single quotes to make sure that any potentially special characters are taken literally.

```
[user@localhost ~]# curl 'https://xxxxxxxxxx.s3.amazonaws.com/xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx/xxxxxxxxxxxxx/x?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAIFKEBR4CLVTDYSLA&Signature=Kv%2B859dJ2eUmLgHdkT%2F9nUJEeRM%3D&Expires=1922517562'
```

The key is single quotes.

Comment: As it turns out - it does not work for all cases... Any other trick?

Comment: What sort of cases is it not working for?  If you're doing any variable substitution in the URL it won't work between the single quotes.

Comment: Works great for me. Was getting an Access Denied without the single quotes. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Aha, I found that curl can download unquoted url (`/` instead of %2F) when such url in "double quotes".